# NGINX and APACHE together or only NGINX?

Tags: apache, nginx

I wonder what are the adventages and disadventages of using NGINX only instead of NGINX & APACHE together. I need very fast server for file distribution nginx looks perfect at first glance however has some drawbacks like:

- doesn't support upload progress bar. Yes I know there is a module which may fix this issue but could it influence performance in bad way, since nginx has to act in different way ?
- .htaccess, I have about 200 lines of rules to rewrite, how much time it may took and how hard it would be to rewrite it to nginx ?
- what about security issue ? Is nginx any more/less safe then apache ?
- any other disadvantages of using nginx only ?

Thanks for resonable answers. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You've highlighted most of the common issues when changing to nginx. Here's a detailed set of answers

1. Not as much as the overhead incurred from loading apache. Apache itself, with its plethora of modules and options, is a memory and CPU hog compared to nginx. This is seen on answers such as this answer: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/71940 . Apache 2.4 is less so, but still more.
2. This is one of the most missed features of Apache, but also one of the most disk-intensive ones. Did you know that Apache needs to traverse all the directories up until webroot in order to read all the htaccess files for every request? The convenience is the pay-off. If you prefer convenience over a slight gain, keep to it. There are ways to improve Apache efficiency by coalescing all your rules into a single htaccess or through the use of `Location` blocks in the config.
3. Do you really think people will not pwn you on your use of PHP before pwning you on anything else? nginx is slightly safer due to packing less stuff that is built-in and requiring cgi processes for almost every mundane task, however.
4. Yes. You lose a whole bunch of apache-specific features such as all the mod_dav stuff. You lose a lot of modules, effectively.

The best use for nginx is in front of Apache if you need Apache modules. Use it as a load-balancer if you might, between multiple Apache instances, and you suddenly have a mixed set-up that is rather...awesome.